# Does setting a has_one or belongs_to association automatically set the inverse association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have two classes: Supplier, and Account. These classes are connected via has_one and belongs_to.

I create a new instance of each.

```
s = Supplier.new
a = Account.new
```

I then set one of the associations

```
s.account = a
```

Does a.supplier automatically get set?

I've tried this and i'm getting a.supplier == nil. I assume I'm doing something wrong but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reload the a instance:

`a.reload`, or `a.supplier(true)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, They both add the same set of methods.

- association(force_reload = false)
- association=(associate)
- build_association(attributes = {})
- create_association(attributes = {})

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference